# number of zero eigenvalues of cyclic tridiagonal matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that following cyclic tridiagonal matrix has two zero eigenvalues for $k=6r$ for any positive integer $r$.

\begin{equation*}
T_\lambda=\begin{bmatrix}
-n_1 & n_2 & 0 &.&.&0  & n_k \\ 
n_1& -n_2 &n_3 &0&.&.  & 0 \\  
0& n_2  & -n_3  & n_4  & 0& . & 0 \\ 
 .&0  & n_3  &-n_4  &n_5&0&. \\ 
 .&.  &.  & . &.&.&. \\ 
.&.  &.  &.  &.&.&. \\
0& 0  &.  &.  & n_{k-2}& -n_{k-1}& n_{k} \\
n_1 & 0 & .&.& 0& n_{k-1}& -n_k
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}